# Magento2: How to delete form address c/d

Tags: magento2

I need to remove the additional two additional address lines from all forms (registration and ordering).

[image]

Does anyone know where I can find and remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a back-end option for it, under customer configuration.

```
Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options > Number of Lines in a Street Address
```